# Sync documents locally with O365

Tags: office-365

I am using O365 site in a company, and they have documents inside libraries, when I want to view a document, it's downloaded to my laptop. How do I keep the document sync that I open it from my laptop and it gets latest modifications from O365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Sync function Offenes from the libary. this requires onedrive. This will "copy" a Version to your Hard Disk and keep Them up to Date.

Comment: Isn't there an option from the document itself to Sync? in case I don't have OneDrive?

Comment: Sure? I think, if you have a office 365 subscription, you have the office package and a onedrive account too. Another solution is to connect the libary with the explorer (works online in IE). You can reach this in the libary ribbon in the top bar. Thsi will be similar to the onedrive solution i think.